# JMeter Pass, fail, Warning?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

So I am running a few tests on Jmeter, I have assertions set up for Pass/Fail. The issue is, I need to set up a "Warning" or "caution" result.

For example -

```
Latency < 500ms = Pass
Latency > 1000ms = Fail 
Latency < 999ms AND Latency > 501 = Caution
```

The above is just an example.. The variation in between A and B would be much smaller.

Does anyone know how to set something like this up in Jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment JMeter does not support `caution` result, the sampler can either be successful or not. You can set a custom response status code, message, print something to *jmeter.log*, send an email, etc. but you cannot get anything but `Success: true|false` without core JMeter changes.

You could try using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) to implement your pass/fail criteria logic, the relevant code which will set sampler response code to `999` and message to `CAUTION` would be something like:

```
def latency = prev.getLatency() as int
def range = new IntRange(501, 999)

if (latency >= 1000) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Latency exceeds 1000 (was ' + latency + ')')
}

if (range.contains(latency)){   
    prev.setResponseCode('599')
    prev.setResponseMessage('CAUTION! High latency: ' + latency)
}
```

If latency will be between `501` and `999` inclusively you will get the next result:

[image: JMeter High Latency Warning]

And failure will look "normally"

[image: JMeter JSR223 Assertion test failure]

More information:

- `prev` is an instance of [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class, see JavaDoc for available methods and fields
- the same for [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html)
- also check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) for comprehensive information on using Groovy for setting custom JMeter samplers failure conditions

Comment: Thanks for this, I believe this will suit my needs for the time being.